# Не переведена строка, что тревога данного типа уже использовалась

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не переведена строка, что тревога данного типа уже использовалась

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ведь была переведена... Переводы иногда слетают что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да. уже было про это: ключом является английская строка, если в ней какой-нить символ поменялся, то все